# Disabled AD users in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2016

Getting the following unexpected in ULS along with other entries in the same correlation ID which mention:

The specified user Domain\Username could not be found.

These users are disabled in AD, and when I search for the user in SP via people picker the user is not found, but when i search via a custom built application within SP, the user is found.

any ideas why im getting these errors in ULS:

Stack trace:
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser.InitMember()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser..ctor(SPWeb web, SPSecurableObject scope, String strIdentifier, Object[,] arrUsersData, UInt32 index, Int32 iByParamId, String strByParamSID, String strByParamEmail, SPUserCollectionType userCollectionType, SPUserCollectionFlags ucf, Boolean isSiteAuditor)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByIDNoThrow(Int32 id)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue.get_User()

Comment: Hi @SP83.

I think this question is best suited for [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). 

If you do have a programming / code related question, here is the right place.

Comment: Hi, But I think this is code related as SharePoint is not supposed to find disabled AD users but the code is resolving Disabled AD users

Comment: Ok. But you have not specify what code you wrote that's breaking. For anyone to help you, they may need to see some codes to identify what's possibly breaking.